# How apps are organised in developer page in the App Store

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, developer-program

If I publish multiple apps under a single developer account, are all of them shows under the developer page in the App Store?

Does app bundle has any impact on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All apps published under a single developer account are shown individually on the developer App Store page by default.

Additional action is required to organise and sell apps under a bundle.

To learn more about apps and games bundle, refer to the Apple Developer web page: [App and Game Bundles](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-bundles/).